# Hanging when attempting to add AppleID to Visual Studio 2019 for Automatic Provisioning

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Initially, when attempting to add the Apple Account into Visual Studio 2019 via the Options Xamarin > Apple Accounts section it hangs. I have left it over the weekend and it still hangs. This isn't very helpful due to no real error or feedback.

I then performed the same in Visual Studio 2017 and got the following error initially...
'Limit of requests to iTunes Connect is reached' <-- or similar.

I have also tested this with different AppleID and also with random characters, with same result.

Then myself and one of the Developers were trying to fix fastlane and now I get the following error message in VS17...
VS2017 ERROR [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9VH1.png)
To summarise I believe it is related to the fastlane setup however I am unable to find specific steps and/or troubleshooting steps to configure correctly for the scenario of developing with VS2019 and building on OSX Catalin.

Any help and/or suggestions much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO! This issue has been reported in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/760934/getting-failed-to-synchronize-teams-with-apple-dev.html) , you can keep monitor this issue there.